# Can this be solved in linear time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given an array of *N* integers (elements are either positive or -1), and another integer *M*.
For each *1 <= i <= N*, we can jump to *i + 1, i + 2, .. i + M* indexes of the array. Starting from index 1 is there a linear *O(N)* algorithm that can find out the minimum cost as well as the path to reach N<sup>th</sup> index. Where cost is the sum of all elements in the path from 1 to N. I have a dynamic programming solution of complexity of *O(N*M)*.
Note: If A[i] is -1, then it means that we can't land on i<sup>th</sup> index.

Comment: Are the non-negative values the costs for taking that path?  Otherwise it's a trivial greedy algorithm: jump as far as you can (search backwards for a non-negative entry from `A[i+M]`), until `i+M >= N`.

Comment: If the array values are costs, then you have a graph problem, with a directed acyclic graph.  Each node `A[i]` connects to all the nodes `A[i+1 .. i+M]` that have non-negative indices.  The way you're storing your graph might or might not be good for a path finding algorithm, but converting to another representation could be done in linear time.

Comment: I think dynamic programming solution of complexity of O(N*M). Even if you use a graph, the nodes of this graph is also O(m*n)...

Comment: @kaitian: There are N nodes, but `O(N*M)` edges.  The question is if there's a way to take advantage of the redundancy:  All edges entering `A[i]` have the same cost.  Clearly you can find *a* path very quickly, and even refine it some to find a local minimum.  (With heuristics depending on the expected distribution of costs.  e.g. find the minimum of `A[i+M-16 .. i+M]`.)

Comment: Please explain what are the costs properties. Apparently negative values are not allowed. Is it correct ?

Comment: @PeterCordes, Yes the non-negative values are costs for taking that path, which add up once we land upon those indexes.

Comment: @fjardon, The cost of a path is the sum of values of all the elements on that path, and each such element is guaranteed to be non-negative. Only those indexes which have -1 as their value are the indexes which can not be included in a path, i.e., we cannot land on those indexes.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your problem right, A* would likely provide your best runtime. For every *i*, *i*+1 through *i*+*M* would be the child nodes, and *h* would be the cost from *i* to *N* assuming every following node had a cost of 1 (so for instance if *N*=11 and *M*=4 then *h*=3 for *i*=2, because that would be the minimum number of jumps necessary to reach the final index).

Answer (score 0):

## New Approach

> `Assumption`: The graph is **not** weighted graph.

This explained approach can solve the question in **linear** time.
So, the **algorithm** goes as follows.

```
int A[N];         // It contains the initial values
int result[N];    // Initialise all with positive infinty or INT_MAX in C
bool visited[N];  // Initially, all initialise with '0' means none of the index is visited

int current_index = 1
cost = 0
result[current_index] = cost
visited[current_index] = true

while(current_index less than N) {
    cost = cost + 1    // Increase the value of the cost by 1 in each level
    
    int last_index = -1 /* It plays the important role, it actually saves the last index 
                          which can be reached form the currnet index, it is initialised 
                          with -1, means it is not pointing to any valid index*/
    for(i in 1 to M) {
        temp_index = current_index + i;
        if(temp_index <= N   AND  visited[temp_index] == false   AND  A[temp_index] != -1) {
            result[temp_index] = cost
            visited[temp_index] = true
            last_index = temp_index
        }
    }
    
    if(last_index == -1) {
        print "Not possible to reach"
        break
    } else {
        current_index = last_index
    }
}

// Finally print the value of A[N]
print A[N]
```

Do, let me know when you are done with this approach.

=========================================================================

## Previous Approach

Although, this explained approach is also **not** linear. But trust me, it will work more efficient than your Dynamic Approach. Because in your approach it always takes **O(N.M)** time but here it could be reduce to **O(n.M)**, where **n** is the number the elements in an array with **no** `-1` values.

> `Assumption:` Here, I am considering the values of **A[1] and A[N]** are not `-1`. And, there are **not** more then **M-1** consecutive `-1` values in the array. Otherwise, we can't finish the job.

Now, do **BFS** described as follows:

```
int A[N];         // It contains the initial values
int result[N];    // Initialise all with positive infinty or INT_MAX in C
bool visited[N];  // Initially, all initialise with '0' means none of the index is visited
queue Q;          // create a queue 

index = 1
cost = 0
push index in rear of Q.
result[index] = cost
visited[index] = true

while(Q is not empty) {
    index = pop the value from the front of the Q.
    cost = cost + 1
    
    for(i in 1 to M) {
        temp_index = index + i;
        if(temp_index <= N   AND  visited[temp_index] == false   AND  A[temp_index] != -1) {
            push temp_index in rear of Q.
            result[temp_index] = cost
            visited[temp_index] = true
        }
    }
}

// Finally print the value of A[N]
print A[N]
```

**Note:** Worst case time-complexity would be same as the DP one.
Any doubt regarding algorithm , comments most welcome. And, do share if anyone got better approach than me. **After all,** we are here to learn.

Comment: Yes, bfs can also be used to solve this, but the worst case complexity is still not improved.

Comment: @PrakharAgarwal Which site this question is on, can you give me the link of it because i've got a **linear** approach but not sure, would it be correct or not. So, first let me check it for you then i'll share when it is done. :)

Comment: it was used for an intra-college coding competition. So, sorry but it's not accessible from outside the college network.

Comment: OK. tell me should i give solution here itself or create new answer section to it.

Comment: You can edit your original answer to add the new solution, so that it can be up-voted if correct.

Comment: The linear approach you mentioned works if we just have to find the minimum number of "jumps" that we have to find to reach N from 1. But we need to minimise the cost first and then in case two optimal paths are present then jumps. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Ok then i request you to put that question on the spoj or any coding site, and let me know when it is added.